# How do I drywall over a partial cement wall?

Tags: drywall, concrete, moisture

I have 9' walls and the bottom foot or so is cement on one wall. What's the best method to drywall over this wall so no moisture seeps in?

[image: far wall with window]

As you can see, there was moisture seeping in down at the bottom below the window. I planned on using a moisture barrier on it, but I'm not sure if this is the best idea out there.

Comment: The step could be extended all the way across the room so that the extra concreate is covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it rained pretty heavily the entire week while I was working, so I waited a day or two before drywalling to see if I could find a leak. I believe whatever was causing the problem was fixed. I think the mold there was from back when that window used to be a doorway.

**Here's my fix:** 
The wall was very unlevel, so I went to Lowe's in search of Lath *(my **brilliant** wife's idea)*! I used it to level out the wall and pretty much re-build the wall without having to actually tear it apart. Here's a shot of the lath-ed wall:

[image: Wall with lath]
I also put some plastic on the bottom to cover the cement area, just in case

And a two shots of the same wall now mudded & tapped:
[image: Mud & tap 1]
[image: Mud & tap 2]

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the answer you were looking for.You must find the cause and fix the water problem prior to installing any drywall.Make sure everything is dry and moldfree before you cover it.

Comment: That's fine, I figured as much. What about attaching it to the cement? Or will I need to since it'll be attached to the 2x4s? Also, will I still need a moisture barrier?